# React Native - cannot build debug when add android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

Tags: react-native, android-manifest

I got error `Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'react-native-start')...` when I added `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config` to `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

I did try adding the same line in `app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and create file `app/src/debug/xml/network_security_config.xml` but still got error.

Here is my `app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">xxx</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And here is `app/src/debug/xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">xxx</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```